# How can I fix this Blazor/Bootstrap 5 CSS issue with "striped" tables?

Tags: c#, css, .net, blazor, bootstrap-5

Trying to resolve a CSS issue that involves Bootstrap 5 "table-striped" and Blazor Razor component display.

I have a simple Blazor/Bootstrap 5 page where I display a table of content pulled from a service at runtime. The content is retrieved and displayed. I do see the Bootstrap CSS for a moment (an initial flash on page load), then the Bootstrap striped CSS seem to be getting overridden by some other dynamic styles that I cannot identify anywhere. In Chrome/Edge dev tools, there are **no CSS** styles applied to the table except the ones I've specified. The table ends up as a simple black and white table, which is incorrect.

I'm using a very basic table format with the new striped CSS as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-success">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="2%" class="text-center" scope="col">ID</th>
            <th width="98%" scope="col">Detail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
@if (eventList.Any())
{
    foreach (var e in eventList.Take(5).ToList())
    {
        <tr>            
            <td>@e.blahblah</td>
            <td>@e.blahblah</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

[Dynamic Table Content - Bootstrap 5 CSS not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDvUV.jpg)

I also removed the possibility that it is the TR/TD generation causing the issue using this approach (which is just to test my theory):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-success">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
            @if (eventList.Any())
            {
                foreach (var e in eventList.Take(5).ToList())
                {
                    @e.blahblah
                }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, the Bootstrap 5 CSS is **still** overridden by Blazor when it gets rendered/displayed. After the initial page load flash (where I see the styling for a split second), the table CSS goes to the simple black and white format.

---

To establish a control to start from, I dropped in some basic/static code and the striped table works perfectly. No issues. The colored, striped table displays properly. For example:

```
<tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Too</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Too</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Too</td>
</tr>
```

[Static Table Content - Bootstrap 5 CSS works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3HoO.png)

This seems to be a bug with the Blazor rendering engine (?). How can I get the Blazor runtime tabular content to retain the Bootstrap 5 styling? What is overriding the CSS?

Please advise.

Comment: In your example screenshot, I see ID and Detail info per row, but the code doesn't line up. Can we see a more clear output of the code? Also, nothing should come after the `@code` block.

The second block with `@if` looks more appropriate, but I would expect to see the foreach wrapping the tr/td and not within a td, if that makes sense.

Comment: I haven't had experience with bootstrap and blazor compatibility. Another tip would be to use the chrome inspector on the table (right-click, inspect) and see what the DOM contains.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Updated the code so it is correct. Also, I put both the static table and the dynamic table on the same page, and the static table appears correctly, but the dynamic table does not. In the Inspector (that's the Dev Tools that I mentioned in my OP), I do not see any CSS applied to the table except that which I've specified. This is very puzzling.

Comment: In the subsequent examples, as noted in my OP, I've simplified what I was doing to strip out any possibility that Blazor was adding something to the TR/TD tags by just spitting out the raw content within a single statically defined TD. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Updated the "broken CSS" screenshot to show the whole table.

Comment: Please add the screenshot to the post rather than a link. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) for instructions.

Comment: Thanks Connor - I cannot post images until I have a "10 reputation". It just converts my screenshots to links... I have tried every way I know how to display the images in the post.

Comment: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/nviqac5u seems to render just fine. Can you spot any differences between your code and this?

Comment: Uxonith - your sample identified the issue. I added a <tbody> tag after the <thead> and everything renders properly now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the info Uxonith. By way of an answer, the issue was simply a missing  wrapper around the / content. For example...

```
<table class="table table-striped table-success">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="2%" class="text-center" scope="col">ID</th>
            <th width="98%" scope="col">Detail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (eventList.Any())
        {
            foreach (var e in eventList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">@e.Id</td>
                    <td>@e.EventInfo</td>

                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```